# NAS share not mounting on linux boot through /etc/fstab

Tags: mount, fstab, nas

I have a NAS share for my Linux server which I mount using the following command.

```
mount -t nfs  172.16.2.115:/shares/OwnCloud /eStore/
```

now to automate this I added the following line in `/etc/fstab`

```
172.16.2.115:/shares/OwnCloud   /eStore         nfs     rw,addr=172.16.2.115,auto       0 0
```

but it is not working and I am not getting any error also.

If I execute `mount -a` then mount is able to mount the NAS based on `/etc/fstab` configuration.

I would like it to mount at boot.

Comment: guys I don'y understand what you achieved by editing my question....seriously it was not required.

Answer (score 0):

edit your `/etc/fstab` with this below line, you don't need to mention the address again.

```
192.168.178.4:/shares/OwnCloud /eStore nfs auto,_netdev,noatime,nolock,bg,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0
```

You can mention the credentials `username=User,password=Pass` also

Comment: It's really the `_netdev` option that's the special sauce, here. That tells the kernel to wait to mount this filesystem until after the network has been enabled.